# H2oApi Java bindings columns endpoint not returning column metadata

Tags: java, h2o

We are developing a Java programm with H2O 3.10.4.7 and we need to retrieve metadata about all columns in a frame such as column names and datatypes. Related question (not resolved, different problem) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44110233/using-h2oapi-java-bindings-to-retrieve-h2o-frame).

Our expectation was that the `water.bindings.H2oApi` Client works just like the REST endpoints and we wanted to use the the H2oApi method `frameColumns(FrameKeyV3 frameId)` described in Javadoc:

> "Return all the columns from a Frame."

but the result does not include any column-related info. 
When we use the REST endpoint via Browser, we get detailed information about the columns in the frame like expected. Examples:

**H2oApi:**

```
FramesV3 params = new FramesV3();
params.frameId = stringToKey(frame, FrameKeyV3.class); // "frame" reference from import process, works

// try with frameColumns()
FramesV3 frameColumns = api.frameColumns(params);
System.out.println(frameColumns.toString()); // "columns" not included in JSON response
```

Result:

```
{
   "column":"",
   "row_offset":0,
   "row_count":0,
   "column_offset":0,
   "column_count":0,
   "find_compatible_models":false,
   "path":"",
   "force":false,
   "num_parts":1,
   "frames":[
      {
         "frame_id":{
            "name":"3d257aae-7266-48a1-8f35-1243436616ab",
            "type":"Key\u003cFrame\u003e",
            "URL":"/3/Frames/3d257aae-7266-48a1-8f35-1243436616ab"
         },
         "byte_size":1928,
         "is_text":false,
         "_exclude_fields":""
      }
   ],
   "_exclude_fields":""
}
```

**REST endpoint:**

http://localhost:54321/3/Frames/3d257aae-7266-48a1-8f35-1243436616ab/columns

Result:

```
{

    "__meta": {
        "schema_version": 3,
        "schema_name": "FramesV3",
        "schema_type": "Frames"
    },
    "_exclude_fields": "",
    "row_offset": 0,
    "row_count": 0,
    "column_offset": 0,
    "column_count": 0,
    "job": null,
    "frames": [
        {
            "__meta": {
                "schema_version": 3,
                "schema_name": "FrameV3",
                "schema_type": "Frame"
            },
            "_exclude_fields": "",
            "frame_id": {
                "__meta": {
                    "schema_version": 3,
                    "schema_name": "FrameKeyV3",
                    "schema_type": "Key<Frame>"
                },
                "name": "3d257aae-7266-48a1-8f35-1243436616ab",
                "type": "Key<Frame>",
                "URL": "/3/Frames/3d257aae-7266-48a1-8f35-1243436616ab"
            },
            "byte_size": 1928,
            "is_text": false,
            "row_offset": 0,
            "row_count": 100,
            "column_offset": 0,
            "column_count": 5,
            "total_column_count": 5,
            "checksum": -7731554748204616990,
            "rows": 150,
            "num_columns": 5,
            "default_percentiles": [
                0.001,
                0.01,
                0.1,
                0.2,
                0.25,
                0.3,
                0.3333333333333333,
                0.4,
                0.5,
                0.6,
                0.6666666666666666,
                0.7,
                0.75,
                0.8,
                0.9,
                0.99,
                0.999
            ],
            "columns": [
                {
                    "__meta": {
                        "schema_version": 3,
                        "schema_name": "ColV3",
                        "schema_type": "Vec"
                    },
                    "label": "sepal_length",
                    "missing_count": 0,
                    "zero_count": 0,
                    "positive_infinity_count": 0,
                    "negative_infinity_count": 0,
                    "mins": [
                        4.3,
                        4.4,
                        4.4,
                        4.4,
                        4.5
                    ],
                    "maxs": [
                        7.9,
                        7.7,
                        7.7,
                        7.7,
                        7.7
                    ],
                    "mean": 5.843333333333334,
                    "sigma": 0.8280661279778637,
                    "type": "real",
                    "domain": null,
                    "domain_cardinality": 0,
                    "data": [ ... ]
            "string_data": null,
            "precision": 1,
            "histogram_bins": null,
            "histogram_base": 0.0,
            "histogram_stride": 0.0,?
            "percentiles": null
    ...
}
```

We are interested in the JSON entity "columns" to retrieve the metadata we need but it is not provided by the H2o Java Api.

Best regards!

Nico

Comment: this might be a "bug" in our `toString`, could you try `((FrameV3)(frameColumns.frames[0])).columns[0].label`?

Comment: I tried 
`FramesV3 frameColumns = api.frameColumns(params);
System.out.println(((FrameV3)(frameColumns.frames[0])).columns[0].label);`

resulting in this Exception:
`java.lang.AssertionError: water.bindings.pojos.FrameBaseV3 cannot be cast to water.bindings.pojos.FrameV3`

Comment: This makes sense since `water.bindings.pojos.FrameV3` extends `water.bindings.pojos.FrameBaseV3` and not the other way around. `FrameBaseV3` seems to be used  in `water.bindings.pojos.FramesV3` by Retrofit for object mapping and does not contain columns. So I guess as long as an `H2oApi` method returns objects of type `water.bindings.pojos.FramesV3` with an `water.bindings.pojos.FrameBaseV3` Array as Frame references the columns will never be contained in the result.

Comment: yes `FrameV3` extends `FrameBaseV3` that's why you can do `FrameBaseV3 x = new FrameV3()` but if you want to grab fields from `FrameV3` class you need the cast and it should work if the underlying object is indeed `FrameV3`. In this case it seems, like you said, that Retrofit instead puts instances of `FrameBaseV3` into the `frames` variable, that's why the cast is failing. On the backend we are setting it properly (that's why you get the proper response through curl). Guess this is a bug and you should open an issue on our JIRA. Really glad someone is starting to use out Java API :-)

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments - this seems to be a bug relating to how we are using Retrofit, please create an issue [in our JIRA](http://jira.h2o.ai/). You can point to this [Retrofit issue](https://github.com/square/retrofit/issues/2123) in it. To be sure also please post the JIRA link on H2O-3 gitter channel.